# some of the global variables are undefined

Tags: javascript, web, global-variables

I'm trying to recreate super Mario bros level 1-1 using Hexi (a JS game engine.)

My problem is with the javascript itself.

I declared several global variables to be used in the game

```
var marioStats = {
'startingPos':[g.canvas.width / 8, 185],
'lives': 3,
'currentPos':[g.canvas.width / 8, 185],
'checkPointPos':[g.canvas.width / 8, 185],
 };  
 var spritesResources = ['resources/graphics/item_objects.png',
                    'resources/graphics/smb_enemies_sheet.png',
                    'resources/graphics/tile_set.png',
                    ];

 var spritesFrames = { 'simpleBlock': [g.frame(spritesResources[2], 15,1, 17,13)],
                    'coinBlock': [g.frame(spritesResources[0], 1,80, 14,14)],
                    'usedBlock': [g.frame(spritesResources[2], 48,1, 14,14)],
                    'gumba': [g.frame(spritesResources[1], 0,4, 15,15)],
                    'koopa': [g.frame(spritesResources[1], 90,1, 14,22)],
                  };

var levelLayout = {
'META': {
  'checkPoints': [],
  'renderArea': 0,
  'horizontalPos': 0,
},

0: [ ['simpleBlock', spritesFrames['simpleBlock'][0], [g.canvas.width /2, g.canvas.height /4]]

],

1: [

],

2: [

],
};
```

now Hexi works like this:

```
var g = hexi(255, 223, levelSetup, thingsToLoad, load);
g.start();
```

after loading "thingsToLoad" array of objects
Hexi will run "levelSetup"

I can access marioStats and sepriteResources inside levelSetup
but when I try to access spritesFrames or levelLayout it gives me **undefined**

```
   function levelSetup() {
        decors.visible = false;
        var level11 = g.group();

        var gameMusic = g.sound('resources/music/main_theme.ogg');
        gameMusic.play();

        var lvlbg = g.sprite("resources/graphics/level_1.png");
        level11.addChild(lvlbg);

        var lvlBlocks = [], lvlEnemies = []; // hold the blocks and enemies of the level to perform collesion on them

        renderLvlSprite(levelLayout[0], lvlBlocks, level11); // this line doesn't work since levelLayout is undefined

        g.state = levelPlay;
    }
```

What am I'm doing wrong here ?

All the variables below spriteResources are undefined !

Comment: what is the error you get in the console for `this line doesn't work` - can you `console.log(JSON.stringify(levelLayout));` above that line to see what `levelLayout` looks like at that point (debugging 101, use the console)

Comment: note: the fact that your code is god awfully indented makes it hard to read

Comment: I used the console **TypeError: levelLayout is undefined** that how I knew levelLayout is Undefined, and sorry for the awfull indentation